# Automate make execution with variable parameter

Tags: linux, makefile

```
SEED = $$RANDOM 
INC  = +incdir+../rtl +incdir+../tb +incdir+../test
comp = ncverilog +access+rwc -uvm -coverage all -seed $(SEED) $(INC) ../tb/top.sv  
logs=mkdir logs;mv test_case* ./logs

test1:  
    $(comp) +UVM_VERBOSITY=UVM_MEDIUM +UVM_TESTNAME=test_case_1; 
    mkdir test_case_1_$(SEED);  
    mv cov_work ./test_case_1_$(SEED);  
    mv ncverilog.log NCVERILOG_$(SEED).log  
    mv *.log ./test_case_1_$(SEED)
      $(logs)
```

Here "SEED" means a random number:

```
make test1 SEED=23679
```

I will run the target `test1` in terminal likewise. But the problem is here I want to run that target 10 times by using any conditional loops. If i want to run the `test1` 2nd time again I need to give like this:

```
make test1 SEED=40244
```

3rd time:

```
make test1 SEED=87797
```

4th time:

```
make test1 SEED=5489
```

Likewise, each and every time I need to give the seed value in the terminal. I don't want it to be like that, if any conditional loops are there to run `test1` for 10 times with 10 different seeds that's reduce a lot of time for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`seeds.txt`:

```
23679
40244
87797
5489
```

Execute `make test1` with `SEED` taken from `seeds.txt` only once:

```
cat seeds.txt | while read in; do make test1 SEED=$in; done
```

Execute `make test1` with `SEED` taken from `seeds.txt` 10 times:

```
cat seeds.txt | while read in; do seq 10 | xargs -I -- make test1 SEED=$in; done
```

You're welcome.

Comment: cat seeds.txt | while read in; do make test1 SEED=$in; done              where should i need to write this sentence. if i write it in terminal it's telling while syntax error

Comment: we should write it in makefile with target, its working 100% fine. but if possible those seed values we can generate randomly in makefile it's very good for the project.

Comment: If you want to generate seed in the Makefile, you can use [`shuf`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/140751/2056) or [`$RANDOM`](https://askubuntu.com/a/400894/2639).

Comment: ya i'm using $$RANDOM for generating seed its working fine, but that number is not appending to the required file